# Google SpreadSheet - handling MM:SS.sss time formats

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to process the following columns in a google-spreadsheet. The Time column represents the minutes, second and milliseconds take to run 1km and I'd like to be able to sum the four values.

```
Split   Time
1       3:13:4
2       3:20:5
3       3:16:1
4       3:26:3
```

I suspect that I need to convert and split the time column into a specific minute and second columns to achieve this goal but would appreciate any advise that the developer may have.

I updated the format of the time column and used the SPLIT / CONTINUE functions

```
Minutes=SPLIT(B2,":")
Seconds=CONTINUE(C2,1,2)
Total Seconds=(C2*60)+D2
```

The table now looks like

```
Split Time    minutes   Seconds Total Seconds
1   03:13:00    3   13  193 
2   03:15:00    3   15  195 
3   03:16:00    3   16  196
```

Still wondering about the most efficient way to convert the Total Seconds value to time.

Comment: Simple `=Sum(B2:B4)` does the trick for me

Comment: Perhaps this answer on Web Applications is of interest:  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57409/29140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LEFT(text, number), MID(text, start, number), and RIGHT(text, number).

In detail:

```
Minutes = LEFT(B2, 1)
Seconds = MID(B2, 3, 2)
Milliseconds = RIGHT(B2, 2)
```

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. I changed the response to minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **SUM** for those values, a la:

```
=SUM(A1:A4)
```

Alternatively, you can use functions such as **HOUR**, **MINUTE** and **SECOND** to extract appropriate values if you want more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

In your original sheet, in a new column:

```
=TO_DATE("00:0" & left($B2,4))
```

Then copy the formula down the column.
This will convert your M:SS (the left 4 characters of your data) to the sheet's system date/time format, for each entry in column B.
You can then sum and format the results as you like.
This assumes there are no leading zeroes on your data. You can add code to check for this, but if your times all have single digits for the minutes value, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Where the source data is a specified (ie *The Time column represents the minutes,second and milli seconds*) then to be able to add to a sensible result (795.013 seconds for the first sample of four) conversion similar to:

```
 =60*index(split(B2,":"),0,1)+index(split(B2,":"),0,2)+index(split(B2,":"),0,3)/1000
```

is required.

To convert the total (assumed to be in C6) to the same absurd format as for input (`13:15:13`):

```
=int(C6/60)&":"&int(mod(C6,60))&":"&value(mid(C6,find(".",C6)+1,3))
```

`